# Link is treated as normal text in Yahoo mail

Tags: web-services, jsp, yahoo, yahoo-mail

On registration on my site i am sending activation message to user that contains a activation link on clicking that link mail id is varified. The link is properly shown in gmail but yahoo mail is not showing it as a link it is showing simply as text how to resolve it.